# Get the latitude longitude for a point on a shape (path)

Tags: c#, geolocation, geometry, geocoding, gtfs

I have a a list of points (latitude,longitude), it's a bus path and around this path I have some points (bus stops), the points are not on the path.

I need to project the bus stops points on the path for compute the traveled distance from the beginning of the path for each bus stops. For that I need the know the latitude and longitude for each stops on the path.

I can compute the distance but I can't project the points on the path en get the new latitude-longitude of the bus stops points.

I search for a formula they do that without success...

Someone have an idea, I work with C# 4.0.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: For each stops I have try to find his closest point on the shape but It's not accurate.

Comment: What are these points not on the path?  X,y into a bitmap or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS has a function called [ST_LineLocatePoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html) from which you can get an exact point using ST_LineInterpolatePoint.

The PostGIS source code is available [here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to calculate the minimum distance between the line (bus route) and the point (bus stop). See http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/pointline/

Comment: Thanks it's good start but I have difficulty to figure how I can get the latitude,longitude of the position on the path..